# ASP.NET MVC wrong encoding using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Some letters in words which are loaded from Excel file are wrong. My app work as follow:

1. I am loading Excel (`.xlsx`) file to wwwroot dir - no problem
2. Reading file and writing its output to console is not good. Some letters are mismatched.

I am using ExcelDataReader.

Saving file to wwwroot

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ImportFile(IFormFile excelfile)
{
    if (excelfile != null)
    {
        // create path to files folder
        string folderPath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "files");
        // create unique identificator for file
        var uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + excelfile.FileName;
        // create completed path with file identificator + file name
        string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, uniqueFileName);
        // create stream
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            excelfile.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
                
        uploadParameters(filePath);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Import", "Admin");
}
```

Reading Excel file:

```
public void uploadParameters(string fName)
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(fName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            DataTableCollection sheets = reader.AsDataSet().Tables;
            DataTable sheet = sheets["Typ jedla"];

            foreach (DataRow row in sheet.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" 
      asp-action="ImportFile" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-data="meals">
        <input type="file" name="excelfile" />
        <button class="ml-2 btn btn-primary width-200" type="submit">Importovať jedlá</button>
        <span class="ml-2 text-danger" id="err-msg-mls"></span>
</form>
```

I changed encoding in Excel no improvement, added web.config with settings for encoding no improvement,even used ClosedXML same problem.

For example this is stored in (`.xlsx`) file Kuracie/Morčacie. This is value which is written to console.

```
Kuracie/Morźacie
```